# React router rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a piece of code that I can not understand. Any explanation is appreciated. My question is what (props) actually is doing here and where it comes from? If I take "props" out, my code is not working.

```
<Route
          exact
          path='/'
          render={(props) =>
            !isAuthenticated ? (
              <Landing {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to='/admin' />
            )
          }
 />
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Please see the docs on the `Route`'s [`render` prop here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func). In short, `props` contains `history`, `match`, and `location` values from `react-router` that your component `Landing` uses.

Comment: For clarity, I prefer to name `props` like in the documentation as `routeProps`, since `props` may lead to shadowing and confusion around what is actually contained in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route is a component of react-router , which matches the url and routes , The code you have given is used for Authentication to redirect user if he is not Authorized ,whatever that is passed from parent has to be passed to the children in this case , the reason they are passing props is to pass the properties of React Router which includes things like history,location and etc. A simple console.log will show you what it is passing and why it is required

Refer to Image below to see what all is getting passed

[image]